# Where is the best place to put my JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, directory-structure

I have a JavaScript file which has many functions that are used by various sections of my website, each of which is in its own sub-domain.

Will it be a good idea if I place the file in the root directory and have all the sub-domains link to that specific one or should I have a copy of the JavaScript file in each sub-domain and link to each one?  The JavaScript file is updated with holiday dates, therefore it is updated regularly. It would mean updating them all if repeated...

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: When I have multiple uses for a script or CSS file, but only want to update it once, I create a *soft symbolic link*   --  Which is basically just an Operating System pointer that can point multiple links to a single file.  That way you update the JS file and it *as if* you updated multiple JS files across multiple sites. IE -->  `ln -s /path/to/your/actual/js/file/javascript.js /path/to/your/symlink/javascript.js`

Comment: @Zak Please post this as an answer, not a comment.

Comment: This is less a programming question than a devops question. There's no objectively "correct" answer since either method has trade-offs. For instance, I would create an NPM package for the library and install it in each site's package.json. Updates would roll out as necessary, and you'd be able to take advantage of tools like webpack that bundle dependencies. But they all depend on circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

To save time (as well as space) and to make your project clean, it will be best to place the file in the main `scripts` or `js` folder.

So in other words, create a folder for all your scripts in the main project's root and place the file in it:

```
site
| - scripts
  | - file.js
...
```

Once that is done, link all other sub-domains to that file.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you. So to be clear, I would include http:/mysite.com/assets/js/myfile.js rather than a relative path?

Comment: @user1753362 Or you could do `../assets/js/myfile.js`

Answer (score 0):

When I have multiple uses for a JavaScript or CSS file, but only want to update it once, I create a soft *symbolic link*

This is basically just an Operating System *pointer* that can point multiple "links" to a single file.

That way you update the single JavaScript file and it will seem like you have updated multiple JavaScript files across multiple sites.

For example

```sh
ln -s /path/to/your/actual/js/file/javascript.js /path/to/your/symlink/javascript.js
```

---

Here is a [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) explaining what Symlinks are.

Comment: Here there :) This *may* work, however, sometimes symlinks are ignored when files are sometimes uploaded. Also, the `ln` command only works on Linux (and Cygwin on Windows).

Comment: This is a good way to confuse yourself/other people - probably better to use a common folder, and alias it via the web server config